# Why does Rails Prelauncher fail when starting with foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, foreman, prelaunch

I'm trying to start prelaunchr on my local machine. I've set up everything the way it's described in https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr, but when I run `foreman start -f Procfile.dev`, the following error trace shows up.

```
$ foreman start -f Procfile.dev
16:10:47 web.1         | started with pid 13070
16:10:47 worker.1      | started with pid 13071
16:10:47 mailcatcher.1 | started with pid 13072
16:10:47 mailcatcher.1 | /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in `method_missing': undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x5fd91c mailcatcher-0.6.4> (NoMethodError)
16:10:47 mailcatcher.1 |  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1057:in `find_active_stub_by_path'
16:10:47 mailcatcher.1 |  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
16:10:47 mailcatcher.1 |  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.6.4/bin/mailcatcher:3:in `<top (required)>'
16:10:47 mailcatcher.1 |  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/mailcatcher:23:in `load'
16:10:47 mailcatcher.1 |  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/mailcatcher:23:in `<main>'
16:10:47 mailcatcher.1 |  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
16:10:47 mailcatcher.1 |  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
16:10:47 web.1         | I, [2016-06-17T16:10:47.972591 #13070]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
16:10:48 mailcatcher.1 | exited with code 1
16:10:48 system        | sending SIGTERM to all processes
16:10:48 worker.1      | rake aborted!
16:10:48 worker.1      | SignalException: SIGTERM
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5.2/lib/action_view/version.rb:5:in `<module:ActionView>'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5.2/lib/action_view/version.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5.2/lib/action_view.rb:26:in `require'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5.2/lib/action_view.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5.2/lib/action_view/railtie.rb:1:in `require'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.5.2/lib/action_view/railtie.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:6:in `require'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:9:in `require'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/all.rb:13:in `require'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/all.rb:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/all.rb:11:in `each'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/all.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/src/prelaunchr/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/src/prelaunchr/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/src/prelaunchr/Rakefile:5:in `require'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/src/prelaunchr/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
16:10:48 worker.1      | /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
16:10:48 worker.1      | (See full trace by running task with --trace)
16:10:48 worker.1      | exited with code 1
16:10:50 web.1         | I, [2016-06-17T16:10:50.125653 #13070]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:5000 fd=11
16:10:50 web.1         | I, [2016-06-17T16:10:50.147037 #13070]  INFO -- : master process ready
16:10:50 web.1         | I, [2016-06-17T16:10:50.147289 #13070]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 13080 exit 0> worker=0
16:10:50 web.1         | I, [2016-06-17T16:10:50.147516 #13070]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 13083 exit 0> worker=1
16:10:50 web.1         | Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead
16:10:50 web.1         | I, [2016-06-17T16:10:50.247875 #13070]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 13086 exit 0> worker=2
16:10:50 web.1         | I, [2016-06-17T16:10:50.247976 #13070]  INFO -- : master complete
16:10:50 web.1         | exited with code 0
```

Seems like something is wrong with the mailcatcher, causing everything else do fail. 
In case it matters, above is the .env file with the example secret key.

```
DEFAULT_MAILER_HOST="localhost:3000"
SECRET_KEY_BASE="sdjgkjsdhfksjhdfkj"
CAMPAIGN_ENDED=false
```

I'm using the following versions:

`$ ruby -v #=> ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]`

`$ rails -v #=> Rails 4.2.5.2`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Update rubygems by

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: That actually worked, didn't seem likely to fix it, but I'm glad I was wrong. Thanks!